# Why is this code returning the original list?

Tags: python

I want to square every number in an input integer but when I try to do it my code returns list of original integers, not integers squared, why?

```
 def square_digits(num):
    lst = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
    for digit in lst :
        digit == digit **2
    return lst
```

Comment: Even if you were assigning to `digit` (you aren't; you are testing equality), assigning to `digit` doesn't update the list.

Comment: You need to update the list with the new `digit` values. You could just do: return `[int(x)**" for x in str(num)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `digit` within the `for` loop is a copy of the value within the list, not a reference to it.  Modifying that value does not modify the list.  (Also, as others have pointed out, you need the `=` operator to modify a value, not `==`!)

Here are two different ways you could accomplish what you're after:

Using an enumeration to modify `lst` in your loop:

```
def square_digits(num):
    lst = [int(x) for x in str(num)]
    for i, digit in enumerate(lst):
        lst[i] = digit **2
    return lst
```

or using comprehension to build and return the list of squares:

```
def square_digits(num):
    return [int(x)**2 for x in str(num)]
```

Answer (score 1):

2 reasons:

1. You are using `==` which is for checking equality instead of `=` which is for assigning value.
2. Even if you were using `=` you are not updating that list.

The code below should work better

```
def square_digits(num):
lst = [int(x) for x in str(num)]

newList = [digit ** 2 for digit in lst]
return newList
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning a `lst`.

```
def square(num):
    lst = [int(x)**2 for x in num]
    return lst
```

Comment: But wouldn't for loop I;m using change the content of lst? If not, what is it that my for loop does? Something does get squared, if not lst then what?

Comment: In simple terms when you do a `for` loop you are just looking at the value in `lst`. The `digit` will hold that value for first iteration say `2` and then when you do `digit=digt**2` you are changing the value for `digit` to `4`. Your `lst` remains unchanged because you are just looking at it not modifying it